# Specializing Weak Factorization to Birational morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

The Weak Factorization Theorem tells us that birational map of varieties over field of perfect characteristic which has resolution of singularities can be factored into blow-ups and blow-downs. My question is what happens when we restrict ourself to birational morphisms instead of birational maps? Can we then assume that it is just a sequence of blow-ups, i.e. that a birational morphism $X\to Y$  can be factored as
$$X_0\to X_1\to \ldots \to X_n$$
where $X_{i}=\text{Bl}_{D_{i+1}}(X_{i+1})$ where $D_{i+1}\subset X_{i+1}$ is a closed subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that every birational morphism is the blow-up of the sheaf of ideals on the range, see theorem 7.17 in Hartshorne.

I don't think that every birational morphism is the blow-uo if a closed subset. Consider (one of the) the small resolution of the $3$-fold ODP with exceptional divisor $\mathbb{CP}^1$. If one blows up the singular point downstairs then gets the full resolution with exceptional divisor $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, so this morphism is not the blow-up of a closed subset.

Answer (score 1):

This is true for surfaces for example. See [1] for general result. But in dimension >2 I am quite sure there will be an example of a birational morphism $f:X\to Y$ which cannot be factored as a composition of blow-up.

[1] Stacks Project : https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C5R